# Xamarin iOS High Storage usage and strange files

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Currently I´m facing with a very big storage problem!
With our app the employees of our customers take pictures that are offline stored and in the office the pictures will be uploaded to a server.
After that the pictures will be deleted from the database and the database will be vaucuumed (sqlite).

Well the problem is that I´m fighting with a big storage usage problem. I thought this came from the database file (maybe a problem with the vacuum) but in my library folder there is a folder named the full qualified name of my app. In this folder there are a ton of files (see the screenshots).

[image: A ton of files]
[image: example files]

**UPDATE:**
This is the content of the file:
[image: content]

What are these files and where they come from?
Are they safe to delete?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: what are the contents of the files?

Comment: @Jason I edited my post!

Comment: I suspect that they are temporary files created as a by-product of taking pictures. Can you correlate their creation with taking a picture? How do you upload the files from the device? Do you extract from the DB and then upload via an API? Could these be temporary files created as part of that process?